# Displaying categories in unordered list

Tags: php, mysql, performance, nested-lists

I ran into a Problem sorting and displaying categories from a database in an unordered list.

I wrote this Code to accomplish the task:

```
$roots = $GLOBALS['sql']->query("SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `category` WHERE `parent`='0'");
$out = '<ul>';
foreach($roots as $root){
    $out .= '<li>'.$root['name'].'<ul>';
    $downs = $GLOBALS['sql']->query("SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `category` WHERE `parent`='".$root['id']."'");
    foreach($downs as $down){
        $out .= '<li>'.$down['name'].'<ul>';
        $bots = $GLOBALS['sql']->query("SELECT `name` FROM `category` WHERE `parent`='".$down['id']."'");
        foreach($bots as $bot){
            $out .= '<li>'.$bot['name'].'</li>';
        }
        $out .= '</ul></li>';
    }
    $out .= '</ul></li>';
}
$out .= '</ul>';
return str_replace('<ul></ul>', '', $out);
```

This seems to have a very long runtime if there are many categories. Is there a more efficient way?
Or in general, is php array processing faster than a MySQL query?

EDIT:
I tried joining the tables and with this query I got the right table.

```
SELECT 
       root.name  AS root_name, 
       down1.name AS down1_name, 
       down2.name AS down2_name 
FROM
            category AS root
  LEFT JOIN category AS down1 ON down1.parent = root.id 
  LEFT JOIN category AS down2 ON down2.parent = down1.id
WHERE 
      root.parent = '0' 
ORDER BY 
      root_name, down1_name, down2_name
```

But how do I process this table in php to get an unordered list? and is this even faster?

Comment: Looks like you need to [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) three tables in MySQL

Comment: That's what I did at first but didn't know how to continue. This is my MySQL:

Comment: SELECT `root`.`name` AS `root_name`, `down1`.`name` AS `down1_name`, `down2`.`name` AS `down2_name` FROM `category` AS `root`  LEFT JOIN `category` AS `down1` ON `down1`.`parent` = `root`.`id` LEFT JOIN `category` AS `down2` ON `down2`.`parent` = `down1`.`id` WHERE `root`.`parent` = '0' ORDER BY `root_name`, `down1_name`, `down2_name`

Comment: Please post it to your question. You can edit it.

Comment: How many rows do you get by that query?

Comment: currently only 3 ^^ but later it will be around 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```php
$rows = $GLOBALS['sql']->query("
    SELECT
        root.name AS root_name,
        down1.name AS down1_name,
        down2.name AS down2_name
    FROM category AS root
    LEFT JOIN category AS down1 ON down1.parent = root.id
    LEFT JOIN category AS down2 ON down2.parent = down1.id
    WHERE root.parent = '0'
    ORDER BY root_name, down1_name, down2_name
");

$tree = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $tree[$row['root_name']][$row['down1_name'] = $row['down2_name'];
}

$out = '';
foreach ($tree as $rootName => $root) {
    $out .= "<li>{$rootName}<ul>";  
    foreach ($root as $down1Name => $down1) {
        $out .= "<li>{$down1Name}<ul>";
        foreach ($down1 as $down2Name) {
            $out .= "<li>{$down2Name}</li>";
        }   
        $out .= "</ul></li>";
    }
    $out .= "</ul></li>";
}
```

In the first loop (`foreach ($rows as $row)`) you build a tree-structured array. In the second nested loop you build your HTML structure.

Comment: It works, but throws some warnings: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). It refers to the innermost foreach

Comment: Oh! I know why. Some of them don't have 2 subcategories, only one. So I'll just check before entering the loop

Comment: Paul, the where probably runs after the joins, which makes your query slower. You need to check for parent = 0 inside your first join to not search for things not needed.

Comment: @LajosArpad, MySQL is smart enough to check the where condition before the join.

Comment: Paul, sorry, but I do not believe you. The from clause is executed before the where. Join is part of the from clause. If you can prove your claim, then I might revoke the down-vote which you deserved by adding misleading comments to "prove" your point. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, why do you believe that you can use root.parent in your where clause? Do you really believe that you can use the field of an unexistent table (root) in your where clause? Because what you say is, that where is executed before join, therefore, root does not exist at the point when the where is executed.

Comment: @LajosArpad, the article you linked is 10 years old. I don't know if it has ever been true - but now it's not. BTW the query is writen by the OP (though i would probably write it the same way) - i just provided the PHP code to organize the sql result. If you need a proof, look at the execution plan. I'm not going to do your homework. If you have a question on that issue - SO is a good place to do that - but not in a comment.

Comment: Besides that, if you put that check into the join condition, then you make sure that in every past and future version of MySQL your code will not search for things unneeded.

Comment: Lajos, please read this article: "For each table in a join, a simpler `WHERE` is constructed to get a fast `WHERE` evaluation for the table and also to **skip rows as soon as possible**." [How MySQL Optimizes WHERE Clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105923/discussion-between-paul-spiegel-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select main_cat.name as main_category, sub_cat.name as sub_category, group_join(',', bot_cat.name) as bot_categories
from category main_cat
join category sub_cat
on (main_cat.parent = 0) and (sub_cat.parent = main.cat.id)
join category bot_cat
on bot_cat.parent = sub_cat.id
group by main_cat.name, sub_cat.name
order by main_cat.name, sub_cat.name
```

This will result in a result set of three columns:

- `main_category` will be the name of the main category
- `sub_category` will be the name of the subcactegory
- `bot_categories` will be the comma-separated value set of bot categories

The query is grouped by category name and subcategory name and ordered by these values.

PHP usage:

```
$previousCategory = null;
$categories = $GLOBALS['sql']->query("
    select main_cat.name as main_category, sub_cat.name as sub_category, group_join(',', bot_cat.name) as bot_categories
    from category main_cat
    join category sub_cat
    on (main_cat.parent = 0) and (sub_cat.parent = main.cat.id)
    join category bot_cat
    on bot_cat.parent = sub_cat.id
    group by main_cat.name, sub_cat.name
    order by main_cat.name, sub_cat.name
");

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $newCat = ($category["main_category"] !== $previousCategory);
    $previousCategory = $category["main_category"];
    if ($newCat) {
        //Handle new cat start
    }
    //Handle subcategory start ($category["sub_category"])
    $bots = explode(',', $category['bot_categories']);
    foreach ($bots as $bot) {
        //Handle bot category
    }
    //Handle subcategory end ($category["sub_category"])
    if ($newCat) {
        //Handle new cat end
    }
}
```

Explanation:

Your program was slow, because it had to send a query for the root categories, a query for each root category to get their subcategories and a query for each subcategory to get their bot categories. This resulted in a lot of requests sent to the database. Instead, you can solve your problem with a single query.